# Как в Python, используя argparse, в аргументе настроить разные типы аргументов?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

Здравствуйте, в программе на Питоне мне нужно переделать прием аргументов из командной строки. Это приложение, в котором есть графическая версия и консольная версия. Выбрать можно только одну из них. В консольной версии принимались также два обязательных аргумента: файл с текстом и файл со словами. Вот так это выглядело:

```
def parse_args():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fuzzy search in text')
parser.add_argument('-g', '--graphics', help='graphical version',
                    action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--console', help='console version', nargs=2,
                    type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                    metavar=('TEXTFILE', 'WORDSFILE'))
return parser.parse_args()

usage: fuzzy_search.py [-h] [-g] [-c TEXTFILE WORDSFILE]

Fuzzy search in text

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -g, --graphics        graphical version
  -c TEXTFILE WORDSFILE, --console TEXTFILE WORDSFILE
                        console version
```

Сейчас мне нужно переделать прием аргументов в консольной версии. Во-первых, должны либо приниматься также два аргумента: файл с текстом и файл со словами, либо принимается только один файл с текстом, а вместо файла со словами используется stdin, откуда берется по слову, пока не завершат ввод. Во-вторых, надо еще в консольной же версии добавить опциональный аргумент, который будет значить, что надо учитывать регистр. То есть это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
usage: fuzzy_search.py [-h] [-g] [-c [-r] TEXTFILE WORDSFILE(если не задан, то stdin)]
```

Но я не понимаю, как исправить существующий уже код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--console` и `--graphics` у вас роль дочерних команд выполняют (как,  к примеру pull, push команды в git утилите). У каждой свои независимые опции. Если бы их имена не начинались на дефис, то можно было бы 
 с помощью [`add_subparsers()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) реализовать.

Чтобы выразить, что `WORDSFILE` позиционный параметр является необязательным, можно `nargs='?'` использовать. Чтобы по умолчанию аргумент был stdin: `default=sys.stdin`.

Если нет цели именно argparse использовать, можно в качестве парсера аргументов командной строки использовать [docopt модуль](http://docopt.org):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Fuzzy search in text.

Usage:
  fuzzy-search -c [-r] TEXTFILE [WORDSFILE]
  fuzzy-search -g
  fuzzy-search -h

Arguments:
  TEXTFILE        input file
  WORDSFILE       optional words file

Options:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -g, --graphics  graphical version
  -c, --console   console version
  -r              case-sensitive
"""
from docopt import docopt

args = docopt(__doc__)
print(args)
```

[Живой пример](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Fuzzy+search+in+text.%0D%0A%0D%0AUsage%3A%0D%0A++fuzzy-search+-c+%5B-r%5D+TEXTFILE+%5BWORDSFILE%5D%0D%0A++fuzzy-search+-g%0D%0A++fuzzy-search+-h%0D%0A%0D%0AArguments%3A%0D%0A++TEXTFILE++++++++input+file%0D%0A++WORDSFILE+++++++optional+words+file%0D%0A%0D%0AOptions%3A%0D%0A++-h%2C+--help++++++show+this+help+message+and+exit%0D%0A++-g%2C+--graphics++graphical+version%0D%0A++-c%2C+--console+++console+version%0D%0A++-r++++++++++++++case-sensitive++&argv=-c+abc+-r).

В аrgparse это можно выразить как:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fuzzy search in text.')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-c', '--console', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-g', '--graphics', action='store_true')

args, rest = parser.parse_known_args()
if args.console:
    console_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parser], add_help=False)
    console_parser.add_argument('-r', action='store_true')
    console_parser.add_argument('TEXTFILE', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    console_parser.add_argument('WORDSFILE', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                                default=sys.stdin, nargs='?')
    args = console_parser.parse_args()
elif rest:
    parser.error("unexpected arguments: " + str(rest))
print(args)
```

Чтобы обойти ограничение, что команды не могут на дефис начинаться, руками  здесь `console_parser` создаётся. Это борьба против течения, к примеру, сообщение об использовании (usage), созданное по умолчанию не слишком здесь полезно — его следует заменить на своё (`add_help=False`, [usage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#usage)).

В качестве альтернативы, можно считать `-c` включённым по умолчанию:

```
Usage: fuzzy-search [-r] TEXTFILE [WORDSFILE]
```

а вместо `-g` запускать отдельную команду: `fuzzy-search-gui`. Обе команды можно создать с помощью [setuptools `entry_points`' `console_scripts` и `gui_scripts`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

А почему вы не хотите передавать в GUI - версию аргументы командной строки? Можно же сделать обязательным аргумент пути к файлу с текстом.
Просто при использовании аргумента-набора (`nargs > 1`) нельзя задать значения по умолчанию для каждой позиции. Но можно выполнить проверку уже после парсинга.

В данном коде я предлагаю передавать все аргументы в любую из версий приложения.

```
import sys
import argparse


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fuzzy search in text')

    # mutex группа - обязателен один (и только один) аргумент
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

    group.add_argument("-g", "--graphics", action='store_true')
    # можно вообще не использовать группу и оставить один аргумент-флаг -g
    # т.е. если его нет - по умолчанию используется консольная версия
    group.add_argument("-c", "--console", action='store_true')

    # текстовый файл - обязательный позиционный аргумент
    parser.add_argument('TEXT_FILE', type=argparse.FileType('r'))

    # набор слов - необязательный аргумент (по-умолч. stdin)
    parser.add_argument('-wf', '--word-file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
    # необязательный аргумент учета регистра; указан - есть проверка
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--register-check', action='store_true')

    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    args = parse_args()

    # тут gui и console - предположительно ваши модули
    # как видно, аргумент console не проверяется
    app = gui if args.graphics else console

    app.start(args.TEXT_FILE, args.word_file, args.register_check)
```

**UPD**

Если передача параметров в графическую версию совсем не подходит, то от обязательного параметра текстового файла надо отказаться, и придется делать проверку вручную.

```
parser.add_argument('-tf', '--text-file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
```

Проверка:

```
if args.graphics:
    gui.start()
elif args.text_file:
    console.start(args)
else:
    print('No File for cli version!!') # или exception
```

Comment: в графической версии я вставляю текст в форму через файловый диалог, поэтому мне совсем не надо передавать гуи расположение текстового файла - это лишняя работа

Comment: @Дарья, обновил ответ

Comment: в обоих случаях по help не будет понятно, что для графики вообще никакие аргументы не нужны, а для консоли нужно вот это, а это необязательно. хочется, чтобы из справки было понятно, буду искать дальше